# Why is print_r still printing out a Json object?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I broke the code up into as many steps as possible to try to figure out what it was doing.

```
         $addsData='http://football.myfantasyleague.com/2013/exportTYPE=topAdds&L=&W=&JSON=1';                

         $addsData = json_encode(file_get_contents($addsData));

         $addersData = file_put_contents("addsData.txt", $addsData);

         $getAdds = file_get_contents("addsData.txt");

         $topAddsData = json_decode($getAdds, true);

         echo "<pre>";
         print_r($topAddsData);
         echo "</pre>";
```

And Here is the result that I am getting...

```
"version":"1.0","topAdds":{"week":"1","player":[{"percent":"25.95","id":"9705"},{"percent":"23.92","id":"10372"},{"percent":"23.72","id":"11440"},{"percent":"23.43","id":"11259"},{"percent":"20.29","id":"9079"},{"percent":"17.06","id":"10048"},{"percent":"16.93","id":"11227"},{"percent":"14.66","id":"10500"},{"percent":"14.10","id":"9964"},{"percent":"13.90","id":"10862"},{"percent":"13.80","id":"9834"},{"percent":"13.55","id":"10355"},{"percent":"13.29","id":"10961"},{"percent":"13.27","id":"9437"},{"percent":"11.87","id":"9912"},
}
```

My understanding from reading the manual is that it should be an Associative array because I am passing in the true parameter. What am I missing here?

Comment: What's the original data look like?  Your URL is broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL you are querying is already returning a JSON string (this can be seen from the URL parameters), which you are then encoding again. As a result, decoding afterwards still leaves you with a JSON string.

For example, if the URL's contents (and the initial value of `$addsData`) are describing an object:

```
{ "foo": "bar" }
```

then after encoding the new value of `$addsData` is describing a string:

```
"{ \"foo\": \"bar\" }"
```

Skip the `json_encode` and things should work fine.

Comment: Thank you. I knew I was close but I think I read somewhere here that the data had to be encoded either using serialize or json_encode to get it to save the file but I guess not. All is working now, man I love stackoverflow, you guys are awesome.

Comment: One more thing, is the reason I cant see the data in my text editor because its an ISO encoding and not utf-8? This is all new to me...

Comment: @MichaelHicks: I really have no idea what "I can't see the data in my text editor" means. What data? What editor? What are you trying? What happens? Too many unknowns, it might be better to think this through and ask another question. You may find the answer yourself in the process of formulating it.

Comment: In the file I am writing to, addsdata.txt but nevermind Im pretty sure its the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You are encoding the data, and then decoding it again.  Don't re-encode the data.  Use it as-is.  Change this line:

```
$addsData = json_encode(file_get_contents($addsData));
```

To this:

```
$addsData = file_get_contents($addsData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably your data isn't valid JSON. You can check it here: http://jsonlint.com/
Your code works fine on valid JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be

```
$arrJson = json_decode('http://football.myfantasyleague.com/2013/exportTYPE=topAdds&L=&W=&JSON=1');
print_r($arrJson);
```

This should give the results as an array.